# How to update React properties after a delay in time and constantly sort an array to the nearest specific number X?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a elevator simulator in React JS with typescript. It's quite simple, there are 6 buttons on every floor for the 6 floors to go to the chosen floor. And when you click on one of the buttons the color changes so you know it's activated. The elevator also got a Up and Down button to go 1+ or 1- but I already done that.

Here is the code for the floors. App.tsx

```
interface Floor {
  floorNum: number;
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
  // Current Clicked Buttons
  const [clickedButtons, setClickedButtons] = useState<any>([]);
  // All floors
  const floors: Floor[] = [
    { floorNum: 5 },
    { floorNum: 4 },
    { floorNum: 3 },
    { floorNum: 2 },
    { floorNum: 1 },
    { floorNum: 0 },
  ];

  // Current floor
  const [currentFloor, setCurrentFloor] = useState<number>(0);
  // Delay Floor Change in seconds
  const [delayFloor, setDelayFloor] = useState<number>(1000);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>React Programming Assignment</h1>

      <div className="elevatorContainer">
        {floors.map((floor: Floor, index: number) => {
          const floorNumber = floor.floorNum;
          return (
            <div className="singleFloorContainer">
              {currentFloor == floorNumber ? (
                <React.Fragment>
                  <UpAndDown
                    setCurrentFloor={setCurrentFloor}
                    floorNumber={floorNumber}
                    delayFloor={delayFloor}
                  />
                  <NumberBtns
                    clickedButtons={clickedButtons}
                    setClickedButtons={setClickedButtons}
                    setCurrentFloor={setCurrentFloor}
                    floors={floors}
                  />
                </React.Fragment>
              ) : (
                <div></div>
              )}
              <div
                className={
                  currentFloor == floor.floorNum
                    ? "singleFloor current"
                    : "singleFloor"
                }
              >
                <p>{floor.floorNum}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is the code for the floor buttons. NumberBtns.tsx

```
const handleClickButton = (floorNumber: number) => {
    setClickedButtons((oldVal: any) => [...oldVal, floorNumber]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="numberBtnsContainer">
      {floors.map((floor: Floor) => {
        const floorNumber = floor.floorNum;
        return (
          <p
            onClick={() => {
              handleClickButton(floorNumber);
            }}
            className={
              clickedButtons.includes(floorNumber)
                ? "floorNumber include"
                : "floorNumber"
            }
          >
            {floor.floorNum}
          </p>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

**Questions:**

So I have 2 questions.

**1:** How to make it when I click on multiple buttons at the same time the delay when switching floors is still the same.

**2:** How to make it that it always goes to the nearest floor
For example, when the elevator is on the fifth floor and you press the buttons 0, 1, and 3 in this order, the elevator must recognize that the most efficient order to stop is 3 -> 1 -> 0.

Comment: I think your question is actually multiple questions, and it would help to narrow down to the thing that is most of a blocker. E.g. are you having trouble with something in the React code? Is the "delay everytime it moves" difficult? Or is the algorithm of selecting the closest floor the hard part?

If it were me, I'd begin with writing a function that returns the closest floor when passed in clickedButtons as a param. That function is independent of your presentational logic.

Comment: Yeah it's mostly the react code delay part cause I don't know how to make it that when there is clicked on multiple buttons at the same time that there is a same delay when switching floors and, not that one time it switches to the floor faster than an other time.

Comment: I think you should revise your question to focus on that part of the problem. And it's better if you can make the question title specific to the technical challenge, e.g. "How do update React properties after a delay in time?" That will make the answers people give you more targeted and give the question the power to help people besides just you.

Comment: But also... I think you can have a `useEffect()` handler that waits for changes in clickedButtons properties and sets a targetFloor useState-based variable. Then you have a second `useEffect()` handler that waits for changes in targetFloor and includes a call to setTimeout inside of it update the currentFloor. For some example code demonstrating these techniques, you can try this article I wrote: https://medium.com/@ErikH2000/react-animations-that-change-behavior-when-props-change-da026cec7548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the distance from the starting floor to all the floors clicked and sort the array from closest to farthest.

```js
clickedButtons.sort(function(a, b){
    return Math.abs(floorNumber-a) - Math.abs(floorNumber-b);
});
```

Just to elaborate, it calculates the distance of two numbers from 1, i.e. for

- a=-10 and b=4, the distances are 11 and 3 respectively. The function returns a positive number, so 4 comes before -10 in the sorted array.
- For a=-1 and b=4, the distances would be 2 and 3, the function returns a negative number so -1 comes before 4 in the array.